# How to replace Password characters with * in connection string?

Tags: powershell

I have not received the right help on this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3221ff86-0eb8-43d9-a84e-54ef76ba123c/how-to-get-the-connection-string-without-password?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

so i am posting here for another option i have in mind:

i have the following script that changes connection strings of level 1100 and 1400 cubes/databases

```
$newConnectionString = "Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password123553;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8"

$AS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
$AS.connect("$Server")

$cubeName = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName($Cube)
$compatibility_lvl = $cubeName.CompatibilityLevel

if ($compatibility_lvl -lt 1200) #1103
{
    $cubeName.DataSources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString
    $cubeName.DataSources[0].Update()

    $lt1200 = $($cubeName.DataSources[0].ConnectionString)
    Write-Host "$lt1200`r`n" -Fore yellow
}
else
{
    $TAS = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
    $TAS.Connect("$Server")

    $TAS.Databases[$Cube].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString
    $TAS.Databases[$Cube].Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)    

    $gt1200 = $($TAS.Databases[$Cube].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString)

    Write-Host "$gt1200`r`n" -Fore yellow
}
```

from these statements:

```
$lt1200 = $($cubeName.DataSources[0].ConnectionString)
Write-Host "$lt1200`r`n" -Fore yellow

$gt1200 = $($TAS.Databases[$Cube].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString)
Write-Host "$gt1200`r`n" -Fore yellow
```

this is what i get as output

> Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data
>   Source=datasource.com;Password=password123553;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8

i should only get back this as output:

> Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8

since i cant find a way to refresh the data source except by reconnecting to the server and print out the connection string without password, i am looking to regex replace the password with the following scenarios:

1. replace the password value with all stars

> Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data
>   Source=datasource.com;Password=********;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8

2. keep the first and last characters of the password value but replace the middle with all stars

> Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data
>   Source=datasource.com;Password=p*******3;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8

3. keep the 1st 3 values of the password and replace the rest with stars

> Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data
>   Source=datasource.com;Password=pas********;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8

i know it would be something like this, but i am not sure what the regex would be for above scenarios:

```
$lt1200 = $($cubeName.DataSources[0].ConnectionString) -Replace($_ "Password=*?;", "Password=********");
```

Comment: who that's a lot of background info for a simple question. do the stars need to be the same length as the password?

Comment: @Jakobii yes they should be same length if possible, so this way we can know the right password was changed. also, i posted as much detail because ive gotten scorned in the past for not providing all details necessary to understand why or what

Comment: i updated my comment below to include example of same length replacement.

Comment: @Jakobii thanks, what about the other 2 scenarios?

Comment: what is your end goal? do you just want to clear the password? are you trying to connect using your windows credentials? or are you just trying to create logs that exclude passwords?

Comment: @Jakobii just create logs that show the connection string was truly changed, and a way to verify it as admins is by being able to check that the new password is correct by maybe seeing the 1st and last characters

Comment: you posted this twice and you accepted and answer for both. Consider deleting one and may be combining the accepted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace with same length as password. not very elegant but it works

```bsh
function Hide-ConnectionStringPassword {
    param(
        [string]$ConnectionString
    )

    $re = [regex]::new("Password=(.*);")
    $match = $re.Match($ConnectionString)

    [string]$password = $match.Groups[1].Value
    [string]$stars = "*" * $password.Length
    return $ConnectionString -replace 'Password=.*;', "Password=$stars;"
}
```

```bsh
Hide-ConnectionStringPassword "Source=datasource.com;Password=password123553;"
```

outputs:

```
Source=datasource.com;Password=**************;
```

Comment: wait...maybe you posted this before i commented. can you make it asterisk based on password length? i dont want to hardcode this way Password=********

Comment: here is a simple function the will return stars with the same length as the password.

Comment: interesting. what if i want to keep the first and last characters of the password value but replace the middle with all stars: Password=p*******3;

Comment: can this part be more dynamic to know where Password is in the connection string? for now, the array [1] mandates "Password" be the second "group" in the string, but is it possible to make it intelligent to recognize it by itself? [string]$password = $match.Groups[1].Value

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look into the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` .net class. it can parse connection strings and convert them into object. you wont need regex to find the password and you can replace the password with whatever you'd like easily.

```bsh
$builder = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]::New('Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password123553;')

$builder.Password
```

Comment: unfortunately, its limited and doesnt support additional keys like Session Character Set=UTF8. thus it results in error: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Keyword not supported: 'session character set'."

Comment: Sorry. I don't know much about Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server I assumed it was similar to sqlserver. I'm sure there is a predefinned way to convert a Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server connection string to an object.

Comment: its fine, i just removed the UTF8 part form the connection string :) ill mark this as an answer. if you dont mind, can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944105/how-to-replace-middle-chars-with-in-a-string