# How to replace middle chars with * in a string?

Tags: powershell

I have the following

```
$builder = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]::New('Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;')

$builder
```

This will print out the connection string as is.

i want to print out the connection string with password showing only the 1st and last chars, and rest of chars in middle as *

```
Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=p************3;
```

how can i accomplish that dynamically (i.e. knowing the length of the password value and then replacing the middle chars with *)?

```
pseudocode: $builder.Password -replace($_ middle_chars, "*")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
function Hide-ConnectionStringPassword {
    param(
       [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
       [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]$ConnectionString
    )
    [string]$FistChar = $ConnectionString.Password[0]
    [string]$LastChar = $ConnectionString.Password[($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 1)]
    [string]$Stars = '*' * ($ConnectionString.Password.Length - 2)
    $ConnectionString.Password = $FistChar + $Stars + $LastChar 
    return $ConnectionString.ConnectionString
}
```

```bsh
Hide-ConnectionStringPassword 'Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;'
```

outputs:

```
Data Source=datasource.com;User ID=UID1;Password=p************3;Connect Timeout=120
```