# How to convert a JSON string to regular string?

Tags: powershell

I have the following connection string

```
{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}
```

I am trying to show the password with ******* , so I need to convert it to `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` type as its easy to replace properties with that. I am using it just fine for non-json structured strings

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]::New('{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}')
```

i am getting this error:

> Cannot convert value  to type
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder

How do I convert it to a connection string thats acceptable by the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` type?

Comment: Do you ultimately need a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instance, or are you just using it for structured access to / display of the input string's fields?

Comment: @mklement0 well i am mainly concerned with eventually using the connection string in this function here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944292/8397835       it works for regular strings just fine, such as "Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553;". so i need to somehow convert that JSON structure to something similar so that it would work with the function. the connection string is generated from the Credential class here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.credential?view=analysisservices-dotnet

Comment: A format transformation to a `;`-separated list of key-value pairs is not enough in your case, because the JSON contains property (field) names that `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` doesn't recognize, such as `Username`.

Comment: @mklement0 hmm, is there another stringbuilder for this kind of structure? i would understand if there isnt, as the JSON structure is new to 2017 server databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to a PSObject first.

```bsh
$Json = '{"Authentication Kind":"UsernamePassword","Username":"someID1","Password":"Yu#gh456!ts","EncryptConnection":true}'
$Sql = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Sql.Password
```

From there you can use the properties to create a new string, or convert it back to JSON.